# Calling IPython.embed() in asynchronous code (specifying the event loop)

Tags: python, ipython

IPython 7.5 documentation states:

> Change to Nested Embed
>
> The introduction of the ability to run async code had some effect on the IPython.embed() API. By default, embed
>   will not allow you to run asynchronous code unless an event loop is specified.

However, there seem to be no description how to specify the event loop, in the documentation.

Running:

```py
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

and then

```
In [1]: %autoawait on

In [2]: %autoawait
IPython autoawait is `on`, and set to use `<function _pseudo_sync_runner at 0x00000000066DEF28>`

In [3]: import asyncio

In [4]: await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Gives:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Envs\[redacted]\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py in _pseudo_sync_runner(coro)
     71         # TODO: do not raise but return an execution result with the right info.
     72         raise RuntimeError(
---> 73             "{coro_name!r} needs a real async loop".format(coro_name=coro.__name__)
     74         )
     75

RuntimeError: 'run_cell_async' needs a real async loop
```

---

On the other hand, running:

```py
import IPython
IPython.embed(using='asyncio')
```

and then:

```
In [1]: %autoawait on

In [2]: %autoawait
IPython autoawait is `on`, and set to use `asyncio`

In [3]: import asyncio

In [4]: await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Gives:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Envs\[redacted]\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py in __call__(self, coro)
     25         import asyncio
     26
---> 27         return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(coro)
     28
     29     def __str__(self):

c:\python35-64\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py in run_until_complete(self, future)
    452         future.add_done_callback(_run_until_complete_cb)
    453         try:
--> 454             self.run_forever()
    455         except:
    456             if new_task and future.done() and not future.cancelled():

c:\python35-64\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py in run_forever(self)
    406         self._check_closed()
    407         if self.is_running():
--> 408             raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
    409         if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
    410             raise RuntimeError(

RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```
````

Answer (score 11):

```
from IPython import embed
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Then `embed(using='asyncio')` might somewhat work. I don't know why they don't give us a real solution though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be possible, but you have to use `ipykernel.embed.embed_kernel()` instead of `IPython.embed()`.

`ipykernel` requires you to connect to the embedded kernel remotely from a separate jupyter console though, so it is not as convenient as just being able to spawn the shell on the same window, but at least it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same problem and found a simple solution: run your `embed()` call in a separate thread. Internally, it will use a separate event loop, which should be fine for most applications.

```
async def mycoroutine():
    await asyncio.gather(asyncio.to_thread(start))

def start_ipython():
    IPython.embed(using='asyncio')
```

**Note**: [to_thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) can take *args* and *kwargs*, which will be passed to your function and be available as local variables in the embedded shell.

This function is new in Python 3.9, but in previous versions you can start a normal thread and wait for it to finish asynchronously, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67308870/317971).